# `clean()` doesnt work properly with foriegnkey

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models `Transaction` and `FamilyGroup` and im making some validations like below

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    income_period = models.CharField(max_length=11)                                         
    property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7)
    number_of_familygroup = models.DecilmalField(max_digits=10)

    def clean(self):
       count_fg = self.family_groups.count()

       if self.number_of_family_group != count_fg:
           raise ValidationError(
            '   Number of family group doesnt match with FG_NO.')

class FamilyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='family_groups')
    last_rent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7)
```

the probelm is when i change `number_of_familygroup` to eg. 3 and i make 3 FamilyGroup objects, it still give me an error `Number of family group doesnt match with FG_NO` , it doesnt let me save the new values. What is the best approach to make it work properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is because you *first* need to construct the `Transaction` *before* you can construct `FamilyGroup`s, so `clean` will run *before* the `FamilyGroup`s are constructed.

Comment: That being said, I do not see why you need to store `fnumber_of_familygroup` in the `Transaction`, why not determine it when needed?

Comment: well, i alos have a third model `FamilyMember` whos foreignkey to `FamlyGroup` and also i have some validations that depend to some inputs in `FamilyGroup` . so the problem is not only here, i was trying to figure out how its done..

Comment: So there is no way around to accomplish this ? thank you for your reply though~

Comment: something else, what if i just want this `validation error message` to appear in the admin and do nothing ? so it let me save what ever i want, but it will remain there?